# LED Flash Light not working when I start my apk in LG Optimus but when I download from play store its working

Tags: android, led, flashlight

> > Please help me to understand where is exact problem.
> >
> > I download from google play store and thats woreking very fine but
> >     when I Run from my code led flashlight is not working.
> >
> > Blockquote
>
> My Code is:

```
 Camera camera = null;
         Parameters parameters;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             final Button FlashLightControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
                FlashLightControl.setText("Set FLASH_MODE_TORCH");
                FlashLightControl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(camera == null){
            camera = Camera.open();
                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                         parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            FlashLightControl.setText("Set FLASH_MODE_OFF");
                         }else{
                   parameters = camera.getParameters();
                          parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                             camera.setParameters(parameters);
                             camera.release();
                             camera = null;
                             FlashLightControl.setText("Set FLASH_MODE_TORCH");
                            }
                    }});
```

> and Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<!-- Camera Permissions -->   

<!-- Features -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Trisha, what problem are you getting exactly? Means which error you getting?

Comment: @Pratik The code is running properly but flashlight is not working means when i click on the button flashlight is not working.

Comment: Let me know the code if possible i tried from lots of source but not working

Answer (score 1):

Check below code, might be it will work for you,

```
Declaration in manifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

//Java code:

    if(camera == null){

    camera = Camera.open();
    parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if(flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)){


            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
        } else if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)){


            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) { }
            });
        } else {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }  

            parameters.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF );
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {}

    }
```